# Easiest way to manage/monitor a flask app?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a small flask app I want to deploy on my server and I'd like to be able to monitor it via an HTTP web interface. I don't need something complicated and I definitely don't want something that's difficult to set up. Previously I've used the Google App engine and the functionality in the Logs tab is completely fine.

The app is served through nginx & gunicorn and uses redis (w/ py-redis) and sqlite (w/ peewee). Ideally I'd like to be able to check the logs for all parts of the system from one place. Is this possible? What's the easiest way?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'd like to deploy it on DigitalOcean. I've always used Ubuntu 12.04 server but I have no preference. They also offer CentOS, Debian, Arch Linux, and Fedora. There's no reason to think I'd be any more competent sticking with Ubuntu than using something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to the predicament and it would be whatever way you are most comfortable with.

You could change all your logging to write to a central database then create a small program which would scrape this data for you. This method also includes configuring a central syslog server:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-centralized-syslog-server

What ever way you want to read these files is fine and all depends how much control you want. You could simply name all the logs based on hostname and `rsync` them to a central server from where you could parse them.

There are also free tools out there which will aid you in choosing you method take a look at:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-centralized-syslog-server

There are also some proprietary systems you could use, such as Splunk:

http://www.splunk.com/

This is by no means a definitive list but should aim you in the right direction.